# Django how to use a HTML tag attribute in views.py?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a view that change a boolean and switch images from it, I already done it but I need to iterate between 12 values (asiento) and i only can point to one of them this is my Django code.

models.py:

```
class Asientos(models.Model):
asiento = models.CharField(max_length=2,primary_key=True)
status = models.BooleanField()
mesa = models.ForeignKey(Reserva)

def __str__(self):
    template = 'Asiento {0.asiento} de la mesa {0.mesa}'
    return template.format(self)
```

views.py:

```
def reservacion(request):
asientos = Asientos.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":
    estatus = Asientos.objects.get(asiento=asientos)
    if estatus.status == True:
        estatus.status = False
    else:
        estatus.status = True
    estatus.save()

return render(request,"first_app/reservacion.html", {'asientos': asientos})
```

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'first_app:reservacion' %}"  method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
{% for asiento in asientos %}
  {% if asiento.status %}
  <div class="col" ><input class="d-block w-100" value="" name="reservacion" type="image" src="{%static "/img/s6.jpg" %}" >{{asiento.asiento}}</div>
  {% else %}
  <div class="col" ><input class="d-block w-100" value="" name="reservacion" type="image" src="{%static "/img/sn6.jpg" %}" >{{asiento.asiento}}</div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if asiento.asiento == '6' %}
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">        </div>
    <div class="col">  <img src="{%static "/img/m1.jpg" %}" alt="">      </div>
    <div class="col">        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</div>
<input type="submit" name="" value="Reservar">
</form>
```

this code change the value only of the first Asientos.objects.get(asiento=asientos) even when i click another one it just change the value of the first object in my DB.

How can i change the value of the object that i click?

Comment: Looks that you need some Javascript. Are you familiar with AJAX-calls? I think those would be most convenient here.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to achieve this. This is probably the most basic:

1. Change `reservacion()` to:

   ```
   def reservacion(request, asiento_id=None):
       if asiento_id:
           estatus = Asientos.objects.get(pk=asiento_id)
           if estatus.status == True:
               estatus.status = False
           else:
               estatus.status = True
           estatus.save()
       asientos = Asientos.objects.all()
       return render(request,"first_app/reservacion.html", {'asientos ': asientos })
   ```
2. Change url to something like this:

   ```
   path('asiento/', views.reservacion, name='asientos'),
   path('asiento/change_status/<int:asiento_id>/', views.reservacion, name='reservacion_status')
   ```
3. Change html to:

   ```
   <div class="row">
   {% for asiento in asientos %}
       {% if asiento.status == True %}
       <div class="col">
           <a href="{% url 'reservaction_status' asiento.pk %}"  class="d-block w-100">{% static '/img/s6.jpg' %}</a>
       </div>
       {% else %}
       <div class="col">
           <a href="{% url 'reservaction_status' asiento.pk %}"  class="d-block w-100">{% static '/img/sn6.jpg' %}</a>
       </div>
       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   </div>
   ```

If you want to use POST method, then one fairly basic approach is with Javascript/jQuery.

1. Change reservacation() to:

   ```
    def reservacion(request):
       asientos = Asientos.objects.all()
       if request.method == 'POST':
           asiento_id = request.POST.get('asiento', None)
           if asiento_id:
               estatus = Asientos.objects.get(pk=asiento_id)
               if estatus.status == True:
                   estatus.status = False
               else:
                   estatus.status = True
               estatus.save()
               return JsonResponse({'status': 'Success', 'msg': 'Status changed'})
       return render(request,"first_app/reservacion.html", {'asientos ': asientos })
   ```
2. Your url is probably right. Should be something like this:

   ```
   path('asiento/change_status/', views.reservacion, name='reservacion_status')
   ```
3. Change html to:

   ```
   <div class="row">
   {% for asiento in asientos %}
       {% if asiento.status == True%}
       <div class="col"><input class="d-block w-100" type="image" src="{% static '/img/s6.jpg' %}" name="asiento" value="{{ asiento.pk }}"></div>
       {% else %}
       <div class="col"><input class="d-block w-100" type="image" src="{% static '/img/sn6.jpg' %}" name="asiento" value="{{ asiento.pk }}"></div>
       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   </div>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $("[name=asiento]").on("click", function() {
               var formData = {"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}", "asiento": $(this).val()}
               $.ajax({
                   url: "{% url 'reservaction_status' %}",
                   method: "POST",
                   data: formData,
                   success: function(msg) {
                       if (msg.status == "Success") {
                           location.reload();
                       } else {
                           alert("Error changing status");
                       }
                   }
               })
           }
       });
   </script>
   ```

I guess that's a good start. This code can be improved in a number of ways, but that's beyond this question.

Comment: im trying but it doesnt work, if i do it it doesnt shows the objects, now i want to explain this, i already have 12 Asientos.objects.all() in my data base so what i want its to show them as a image and to change its boolean value when the user clicks them, i just cant get every object separated, in the html that you send me it doesnt shows the divs but everything seems to be ok i dont known why it doesnt shows them

Comment: If you're not seeing divs, then everything is not ok. Are you sure you used `{% for asiento in asientos %}` in HTML and included `asientos` in the context?

Comment: yea, now i already have the divs but i can only change the status of the first one, im pointing to asiento_id in estatus but it only takes the first one (it prints the 12 divs and they are clickable but no matter wich one i click it only change the first one), i can even print the id of every one from 1 to 12 but cant get the status of each one

Comment: @charlie, I have changed the code for the second example with POST method. I guess that's the one you're trying to implement, You should be able to debug this from here on yourself. I can't really test this code, but it should work.

Comment: i still cant done it, if i use your code it throws me an error, i have use pafrt of it into my code, but still only can change the first value, if you can help me in this part its the only thing i now need, is there a way to say to my view that i am selecting another object not the first one?, let me put my new code:

Comment: You're only using part of my code. You didn't change HTML code the way I suggested. It doesn't work, because you're submitting a form with several asiento inputs.

Comment: Like i said i used your entire code and it throws me an error so i started to use part of it, let me show you the error, the first option you give me doesnt shows anything, and the second says the url its wrong

Comment: Reverse for 'reservacion_status' not found. 'reservacion_status' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: my urls looks like this : urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^relative/$',views.relative,name='relative'),
    url(r'^crearcuenta/$',views.crearcuenta,name='crearcuenta'),
    url(r'^reservacion/$',views.reservacion,name='reservacion'),
    url(r'^inicio/$',views.inicio,name='inicio'),
    url(r'^user_login/$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^$',views.usuarios,name='users'),
    url(r'asiento/change_status/', views.reservacion, name='reservacion_status')

Comment: i have manage to change the ajax code to fix it $.ajax({
                url: "{ 'reservacion_status' }",, but i still get a blank page i doesnt need to use POST if theres another form to show the data from my DB wich i have 12 objects and can get them and change its value thats all

Comment: I've made a mistake there in javascript, should have been `{% url 'reservacion_status' %}` and not `{% 'reservaction_status' %}`. I gave two examples. One with GET and another with POST. I cannot test this, but I use similar code in most of my projects. You still need to iron our the code to fit your project exactly.